# Class Demo\Helloworld\Controller\Post\index\Interceptor does not exist

Tags: magento2, database, interceptor

I am trying to get data from a database table, my code of Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Demo\Helloworld\Controller\Post;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_postFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Pixelpro\Helloworld\Model\PostFactory $postFactory
        )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        
        $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
        $collection = $post->getCollection();
        foreach($collection as $item){
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($item->getData());
            echo "</pre>";
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

I tried to run these commands but the error still appears

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

the error :

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class
> Demo\Helloworld\Controller\Post\index\Interceptor does not exist
> Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class
> Demo\Helloworld\Controller\Post\index\Interceptor does not
> exist#1
> Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at
> [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]

Comment: Try running php bin/magento setup:di:compile if you are not in developper mode. Also make sure that your class path reflect your folder path. Your file should be located there : app/code/Demo/Helloworld/Controller/Post/Index.php. your file name should also be Index.php and not index.php

Comment: I renamed it to Index.php instead of index.php but the error still available, and I am on the developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

just remove generated folder and hit below cmd. make sure your controller name is correct Index.php.

```
rm -rf generated/* var/*;
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I executed these commands but the error still available, and the last command I got this : Deprecated Functionality: Array and string offset access syntax with curly
  braces is deprecated in /home/626252.cloudwaysapps.com/cgxbwegvut/public_ht
  ml/app/code/Magefan/Blog/Model/Import/Wordpress.php on line 125